# how to commit the changes inside one @Transactional method , which is called in side another @Transactional method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am getting StaleStateException exception while calling @Transactional method for saving one data and again immediately fetch the data inside another @Transactional method.
Hibernate is making version. Is there any solution for this scenario.

exception : nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0;

And my code is

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteByUserCert(Long uid) {
  log.info("inside delet");
  utilsService.setDeletedFlagForUser(uid);
  Optional<UserDetailsBE> UserDetails= UserRepository.findByUid(vin);
  if (UserDetails.isPresent()) {
    try{
        UserDetailsBE user = UserDetails.get();
        // set of business logic 1
        //set of business logic 2
        UserRepository.delete(user);

        } catch(Exception e){
        
        }
```

utilsService.java

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void setDeletedFlagForUser(Long uid){
    Optional<UserDetailsBE> UserDetails= UserRepository.findByUid(vin);
    if (!UserDetails.isPresent()) {
        UserDetailsBE user = UserDetails.get();
        user.setDeleted(true);
        UserRepository.save(user);
     }
   }
```

and repository class:

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDetailsBE, Long> 
    {
```